# Shift column values to left if previous column is empty in pandas

Tags: pandas

Need to shift the entire column to the left if the previous column has all NaN values, in the example in below column c will be replaced by values of column d since column c is entirely empty. After shift we also need to delete the transferred columns, so column d will be dropped

INPUT:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select columns by mask for test if all values are missing, get next column for both shifted and use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) per `axis=1` by mask:

```
data = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b':[1]+ [None]*4,
    'c': None,
    'd': [9,8,7,6,5],
   
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


m1 = df.isna().all()
m2 = m1.shift(fill_value=False)

df.loc[:, m1 | m2] = df.loc[:, m1 | m2].shift(-1, axis=1)
print(df)
   a    b  c   d
0  1  1.0  9 NaN
1  2  NaN  8 NaN
2  3  NaN  7 NaN
3  4  NaN  6 NaN
4  5  NaN  5 NaN
```

Last remove shifted columns:

```
out = df.loc[:, ~(df.isna().all() & m2)]
print(out)
   a    b  c
0  1  1.0  9
1  2  NaN  8
2  3  NaN  7
3  4  NaN  6
4  5  NaN  5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this programmatically, and since you want to drop the all-NaNs you don't need to change the data, just [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns:

```
cols = df.isna().all()
idx = cols.index

out = (df.drop(columns=idx[cols])
         .rename(columns=dict(zip(idx[cols.shift(fill_value=False)],
                                  idx[cols])))
      )
```

Or, with [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
cols = df.notna().any()

out = df.loc[:, cols].set_axis(cols[cols.shift(fill_value=True)].index, axis=1)
```

As this will leave the underlying data untouched, this operation should be very fast.

Output:

```
   a    b  c
0  1  1.0  9
1  2  NaN  8
2  3  NaN  7
3  4  NaN  6
4  5  NaN  5
```

Intermediate dictionary (1st approach):

```
dict(zip(idx[cols.shift(fill_value=False)], idx[cols]))
# {'d': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `Nan` columns and rename:

```
cols = df.notna().any()
new_df = df.loc[:,cols]
new_df.columns = df.columns[:cols.sum()]
new_df
   a    b  c
0  1  1.0  9
1  2  NaN  8
2  3  NaN  7
3  4  NaN  6
4  5  NaN  5
```

one liner:

```
df.loc[:, cols].set_axis(df.columns[:cols.sum()], axis = 1)
   a    b  c
0  1  1.0  9
1  2  NaN  8
2  3  NaN  7
3  4  NaN  6
4  5  NaN  5
```